# After starting Laravel with ./vendor/bin/sail up how to connect to MySQL using Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, docker, laravel-sail

I'm trying to connect to mysql on Docker.
I used `./vendor/bin/sail up` to start Laravel.

The command `docker container ls` returns the followings:

```
ID  88df79d8937f
IMAGE   mysql:8.0
COMMAND "docker-entrypoint.s…"
CREATED 38 minutes ago
STATUS  Up 38 minutes (healthy)
PORTS   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
NAMES   laravel-app_mysql_1
```

I used `docker container inspect` to find IPAddress:

```
❯ docker container inspect 88df79d8937f | grep "IPAddress"
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPAddress": "172.24.0.4",
```

In Sequel Pro, I use 172.24.0.4 for Host, sail for username, password for Password.

I get an error telling "Unable to connect to host 172.24.0.4, or the request timed out."

How can I use SequelPro or another DB client to connect to Docker MySQL?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should just put in localhost as the host, as it is exposed this way on the host.

> Host: 127.0.0.1 or localhost
>
> Username: what you put in your .env under
> [DB_USERNAME](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/stubs/mysql.stub#L8)
>
> Password: what you put in your .env under
> [DB_PASSWORD](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/stubs/mysql.stub#L9)

Bonus (relevant but not needed for this problem):

172.24.0.4 is for container to container communication. Which can change every restart of your containers so it's better not to use their ip's but [reference each other using their container name](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#ip-address-and-hostname).